# How to PHP debug a single website in VS Code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

The setup;

1. Windows OS (well, I have to)
2. WAMP as server
3. VS Code for IDE
4. browser Google Chrome

Everything works fine except... If I am in the middle of debugging my website, and I flip tabs (in Chrome) to my phpMyAdmin to check a db value, VS Code/Xdebug will start debugging phpMyAdmin (same deal with other "localhost" sites)

At this point, everything appears to just lockup and quit working.  I understand it's because xdebug is catching warnings/errors etc. on the "other" websites. Clicking through the "call Stack" and clicking the "continue" button does not always (rarely) keep things moving along.

**How do I set vs code/xdebug to monitor only a single website?**

my main web application is served [locally] at `http://reqapp.dev`
my phpMyAdmin is at `http://wamp/phpmyadmin/`
and other sites are at `http://localhost/path/to/website/`

I never had an issue in Aptana Studio doing the same thing (same dev environment actually) but it would "launch" the website for debugging, and I think it used a special port. I don't know how to replicate this with VS Code.

EDIT:
most sites are defined as virtual hosts

httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/Users/chadmeyers/Sites
    <Directory  "c:/Users/chadmeyers/Sites">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName wamp
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName reqApp.dev
    DocumentRoot "c:/users/chadmeyers/sites/aaappdev/public_html"
    <Directory  "c:/users/chadmeyers/sites/aaappdev/public_html/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And php.ini

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension ="c:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.5-7.0-vc14-x86_64.dll"

xdebug.remote_enable = On
xdebug.remote_autostart = On
xdebug.profiler_enable = On
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = On
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="c:/wamp64/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 5
xdebug.var_display_max_children = 256
xdebug.var_display_max_data = 1024
```

Within VS Code PHP Debug I have these settings, but it makes no difference which "profile" I use

```
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Listen for XDebug",
      "type": "php",
      "request": "launch",
      "port": 9000
    },
    {
      "name": "Launch currently open script",
      "type": "php",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${file}",
      "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
      "port": 9000
    },
    {
      "name": "debug FRAaap",
      "type": "php",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${file}",
      "cwd": "C:\\Users\\chadmeyers\\Sites\\aaAppDev\\public_html\\",
      "port": 9000
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Xdebug settings? How do the sites are defined in WAMP? As Virtual Hosts (so each uses own domain name) or what? If you are using cookie/query parameter to initiate debugging session then it should not affect other sites (as it should be per domain). But maybe you have `xdebug.remote_autostart` enabled -- in such case xdebug will try to debug every single script. As for the _possible_ reason for lock up - xdebug may be starting another debug session and VS Code might be supporting no more than one at a time .. so it sits and waits until current one will be completed.

Comment: you got it for the lockup.  I'll post my xdebug settings

Comment: Well .. you have `xdebug.remote_autostart = On`. Xdebug itself will try to debug *every single request on every domain* (even in CLI mode -- in console/terminal). Disable that option and pass "debug me" flag in another way (either cookie (look for xdebug browser extensions) or GET/POST parameter (IDE/editor should be adding it on debug to the URL requested_). P.S. If you need more than 1 simultaneous debug session -- try PhpStorm (it can do that, after increasing the limit manually from default 1). It can also ignore requests from another (not yet configured) domains. It's paid software though

Comment: Use XAMPP and try this: https://gist.github.com/odan/1abe76d373a9cbb15bed

Answer (score 1):

based on some tips about `xdebug.remote_autostart` I did some more searching and came across [this article](https://www.sourcetoad.com/resources/debugging-php-save-time-with-xdebugs-remote-autostart/) which gave me a better understanding.  I turned off `xdebug.remote_autostart` As suggested, [the Chrome Xdebug helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) is also a big help, automagically starting the debug session.

Now if I want to start Xdebug I just append `XDEBUG_SESSION_START` and a random string to my url and it works, or use the extension.

I still have lots to figure out to really make this work great, but this will do just fine for now.